# Gradle skip module when building another

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I am creating an app, which basically consists of 3 JAVA modules:

- AndroidApp (version for android, depends on HTTPServer)
- HTTPServer (core server functionality)
- HTTPServerStandalone (wrapper around core, so it can be launched standalone usong Java SE, depends on HTTPServer)

So there is no dependency between AndroidApp and HTTPServerStandalone. They don't need each other.

Now I've encountered a problem, because I can not build HTTPServerStandalone without Android SDK installed, because settings.gradle contains an include for all 3 modules. Is there a way, how can I prevent AndroidApp from being included when I am building HTTPServerStandalone?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it can - settings.gradle:

```
def localProperties = new File("$rootDir", "local.properties")
if (localProperties.exists()) {
    Properties properties = new Properties()
    localProperties.withInputStream { instr ->
        properties.load(instr)
    }

    def sdkDir = properties.getProperty('sdk.dir')
    if (sdkDir != null) {
        def folder = new File(sdkDir);
        if (folder.isDirectory()) {

            include ':AndroidApp';

        } else {
           println "WARINING: SKIPPING :AndroidApp MISSING '" + sdkDir + "' IS NOT A DIRECTORY";
        }
    } else {
       println "WARINING: SKIPPING :AndroidApp MISSING 'sdk.dir' IN FILE $rootDir/local.properties";
    }
} else {
    println "WARINING: SKIPPING :AndroidApp MISSING FILE $rootDir/local.properties";
}

include ':HTTPServerStandalone', ':HTTPServer'
```

Do you know a better solution?